# Failed to execute SQL script statement (stored procedure in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I try to create stored procedure in MySQL:

```
create PROCEDURE sp_attachAuthorToBook(
IN  _bookId      INT,
IN  _authorName VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN

 declare _authorId int
 select _authorId = id from Authors where name = _authorName

 IF (_authorId is null) THEN

   INSERT INTO Authors (name)
   VALUES (_authorName)
   SELECT _authorId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

 END IF

 insert into Books_Authors (bookID, authorID)
 values (_bookId, _authorId)

END;
```

But I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'select _authorId = id from Authors where name = _authorName IF
>   (_authorId is nul' at line 1

Seems like script is too large to be executed. Line just broken near: 
 `IF (_authorId is null) THEN` -- `IF (_authorId is nul`

Comment: You have write code that looks like SQL Server code.  I suggest you study up a bit on MySQL if you are using that database.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Where it looks like I use SQL server code ?

Comment: . . `scope_identity()` is very specific to SQL Server (well, T-SQL).

Comment: Ok, @Gordon Linoff, I agree, I changed it with LAST_INSERT_ID(). But it doesn't solve my problem. Problem is in another...

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your delimiters. By default it's ";". But you need internal delimiter, so :

```
DELIMITER |
create PROCEDURE sp_attachAuthorToBook(
IN  _bookId      INT,
IN  _authorName VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN

 declare _authorId int;
 select _authorId = id from Authors where name = _authorName;

 IF (_authorId is null) THEN

   INSERT INTO Authors (name)
   VALUES (_authorName);
   SELECT _authorId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

 END IF;

 insert into Books_Authors (bookID, authorID)
 values (_bookId, _authorId);

END|
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working code on SQLYOG: Please try in this way

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/ PROCEDURE `test`.`sp_attachAuthorToBook`(
    IN  _bookId      INT,
    IN  _authorName VARCHAR(20)
    )
    BEGIN
    DECLARE _authorId INT;

    SELECT id INTO _authorId FROM Authorss WHERE `name` = _authorName;

     IF _authorId IS NULL THEN
       INSERT INTO Authorss(`name`) SELECT _authorName;
       SET _authorId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
     END IF;

     INSERT INTO Book_Authors(bookID, authorID) SELECT _bookId, _authorId;


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```